# click to activate window is not working at edge of window

Tags: gnome-shell

(Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, GNOME Shell)

This is really starting to drive me nuts. I have a bunch of windows open and I see the edge of window A behind window B. I think that I can click on window A and it will come to the front. It does not.

It seems that if I click near the edge of window A, it thinks I am doing the wrong thing and ignores me. If enough of window A is visible so that I can click 10 or so pixels in from the edge of the window, then it will activate window A.

This is really obnoxious. If I see a 1-pixel strip of a window and I click on that window, I want to see that window come to the front.

Is there a super-tweaks or something that will let me change the default behavior?

Oddly, this may be application-specific. For example:

1: If a firefox window is in front of an Encryptr window, a click on the edge of the back window will work.

2: If a firefox window is behind a firefox window, a click on the edge of the back window will not work.

3: If a Terminal window is behind a firefox window, a click on the edge of the back window will not work.

4: If a firefox window is behind a Terminal window, a click on the edge of the back window will work.

Comment: Switch to XServer Session (on login screen) and try again (currently you are describing Wayland behavior). If it doesn't work, start `xev`(which does not work with wayland) and copy the events into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Turning off Wayland works great. I did this by editing the file at /etc/gdm3/custom.conf (requires sudo) and un-commenting the line which has "#WaylandEnable=false".